# iOS AudioQueue - What happens with a stereo microphone when requesting 1 channel?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, audio, audioqueue

iOS AudioQueue - What happens with a stereo microphone when requesting 1 channel?

Using "AudioStreamBasicDescription" and setting "mChannelsPerFrame" to 1.
What happens if a user has an external **stereo** microphone connected?
Is one channel selected, are the channels mixed, does it fall back to the in-built microphone?

I have been unable to find anything in the Apple documentation regarding this.

Thanks!

Comment: I would do some experiments

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have access to a stereo microphone or the equipment to connect one to an iOS device at this time. 
I figured I would ask here to see if anyone has tried this before and/or knows the answer :)

Comment: to write iOS code you need a mac computer which will have built in stereo mic just execute your code in xcode and run an iphone simulator to test ... no need for anything other than a mac

Comment: Thanks! However, I've looked into this - the built-in stereo microphone input seems to give exactly the same input on both channels (tested in other applications such as Adobe audition). Therefore, it's hard to figure out what's actually happening with the channel selection. Also, it's hard to know if the behaviour of the simulator is the same as a physical device  (particularly as a physical device using an external microphone). From experience, the iOS simulator often is not an accurate representation of the behaviour on a real device.